# If - Then with multiple characters and conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, character, grepl

I hope someone can help me as my current approach with grepl does not lead to anything that works

I have several categories (stored as characters). I now want to build a variable that takes different values for different categories.

The data looks like the following

```
category                                 

Candidate Biography                        
Candidate Biography                         
Candidate Biography                         
Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance       
Justice, Candidate Biography, Economy       
Candidate Biography, Jobs                   
Economy, Education, Candidate Biography    
Economy, Civil Rights, Candidate Biography
```

Now I want to create new variables that can take different values according to the category like shown below

```
category                                 CandBio   Economy  CivilRights   Family
Candidate Biography                         1         0          0           0
Candidate Biography                         1         0          0           0
Candidate Biography                         1         0          0           0
Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance       0.5       0.5        0           0
Justice, Candidate Biography, Economy       0.33      0.33       0.33        0
Candidate Biography, Jobs                   0.5       0.5        0           0
Economy, Education, Candidate Biography     0.33      0.33       0           0.33
Economy, Civil Rights, Candidate Biography  0.33      0.33       0.33        0
```

Each category has a specific factor for each variable (and can load on different categories). E.g. "Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance" loads on CandBio and Economy 0.5 each. Categories re-occur for many observations within the dataset. (in total 49k obs with 120 different categories that need to be aggregated into 10 variables like CandBio, Economy, CivilRights, etc. in the example)

I first tried it combining ifelse and grepl, but I realized that grepl is very sensitive to order and that I can get fault categorizations for each category depending on how I structure my ifelse. Also I tried to get vactors with all category terms that share a similar number and to then include the vector in the grepl function but that didnt work either.

So I am looking for any solution that helps me to assign my weights to variable depending on the category text.

I hope I could clearly describe my problem and I am looking forward to any help, that is very much appreciated! Many thanks beforehand!

EDIT: So far I tried it this way, but with no success:

```
clintontvad$CandidateBiography <- ifelse(ifelse(grepl("Candidate Biography", clintontvad$subjects),1,
                                                ifelse(grepl("Candidate Biography, Marriage, Gays and Lesbians, Civil Rights, Immigration, Trade, Energy, Workers", clintontvad$subjects), 0.125, 
                                                ifelse(grepl("Candidate Biography, Terrorism, Islam, Foreign Policy, Nuclear, Iran", clintontvad$subjects),0.17,
                                                ifelse(grepl("Children, Candidate Biography, Families, Education, Debt, Economy, Jobs", clintontvad$subjects),0.17,
                                                       ifelse(grepl("Candidate Biography, Children, Education, Health Care, Women", clintontvad$subjects), 0.2,
                                                              ifelse(grepl("Candidate Biography, Civil Rights, Islam, Gays and Lesbians, Women", clintontvad$subjects), 0.2,
                                                                     ifelse(grepl("Candidate Biography, Economy, Election, Children, Families", clintontvad$subjects), 0.2,
                                                                            ifelse(grepl("Children, Education, Women, Economy, Families", clintontvad$subjects), 0.2,
                                                                                   ifelse(grepl("Job Accomplishments, Abortion, Women, Health Care, Climate Change, Marriage", clintontvad$subjects), 0.2,
                                                                                          ifelse(grepl("Women, Civil Rights, Gays and Lesbians, Foreign Policy, Canddate Biography", clintontvad$subjects), 0.25, 
                                                                                                 ifelse(grepl("Poverty, Health Care, Candidate Biography, Terrorism", clintontvad$subjects), 0.25,
                                                                                                        ifelse(grepl("Job Accomplishments, Foreign Policy, Health Care, Children", clintontvad$subjects), 0.25,
                                                                                                               ifelse(grepl("Foreign Policy, Terrorism, Candidate Biography", clintontvad$subjects),0.25,
                                                                                                                      ifelse(grepl("Ethics, Terrorism, Candidate Biography", clintontvad$subjects),0.25, 0)))))))))))))
```

Comment: I don't completely follow your logic, but I can suggest that you move away from storing your categories in this CSV format, which is unnormalized, and therefore tricky to work with.  Instead, consider having each category on a separate line.

Comment: Say you've got categories A,B,D,F,C (intentionally unordered). Are the loads always evenly split?

Comment: Thx... Basically what I want is that a variable takes specific values for a specific string or string combination. Different strings or string combinations can lead to the same value. I guess grepl is not the best solution for this, any ideas what else I can do to make a variable take a specific value for a specific string? Something like if "ABD, ACE, YXZ", "DEF" or "DAB, EDF" occur then Var1 takes 0.33 if "ABD, DAB" or "XYZ" occur VAR1 takes the variables 0.5 if "ABD" occurs VAR1 takes value 1 and 0 else.

Comment: First, you ought to create a data structure representing the mapping you want, eg, `myvars = list(CandBio = "Candidate Biography", Economy = c("Economy", "Campaign Finance"))` From there, it will be more straightforward for others to help with coding, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your example correctly, then the weights for the new variables depend on the number of categories in each row. In that case you can use a two step approach. First create your new variables and afterwards divide by the number of matched categories.

```
d <- data.frame(category = c("Candidate Biography", "Candidate Biography", "Candidate Biography", 
                             "Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance", 
                             "Justice, Candidate Biography, Economy", "Candidate Biography, Jobs", 
                             "Economy, Education, Candidate Biography", 
                             "Economy, Civil Rights, Candidate Biography"))

# create a list with all your new variables and their respective categories
categories <- list(
  CandBio = c("Candidate Biography"),   
  Economy = c("Campaign Finance", "Economy", "Jobs"), 
  CivilRights = c("Justice", "Civil Rights"), 
  Family = c("Education")
  )

# create the new variables
for (i in seq_along(categories)) {
  d[names(categories)[i]] <- grepl(paste0(categories[[i]], collapse = "|"), d[, "category"])
}

# divide by number of matched categories
d[, -1] <- d[, -1]/rowSums(d[, -1])

d
                                    category   CandBio   Economy CivilRights    Family
1                        Candidate Biography 1.0000000 0.0000000   0.0000000 0.0000000
2                        Candidate Biography 1.0000000 0.0000000   0.0000000 0.0000000
3                        Candidate Biography 1.0000000 0.0000000   0.0000000 0.0000000
4      Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance 0.5000000 0.5000000   0.0000000 0.0000000
5      Justice, Candidate Biography, Economy 0.3333333 0.3333333   0.3333333 0.0000000
6                  Candidate Biography, Jobs 0.5000000 0.5000000   0.0000000 0.0000000
7    Economy, Education, Candidate Biography 0.3333333 0.3333333   0.0000000 0.3333333
8 Economy, Civil Rights, Candidate Biography 0.3333333 0.3333333   0.3333333 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understood correctly, here is one way to do it. You need a vector of matches for your category, and you will want to keep an eye on the case or if you have any special characters. But this should get your started. Let me know if you have any issues with it. Also, in hindsight, I named too many things "category" but you should get the idea. `category1` `2` and `3` refer to whatever makes up your broader groups (e.g., `Economy` and `CivilRights`). Last, if this is slow, it will probably be a lot faster to use a function from `stringi` instead of `grepl`. I can post an edit if this base solution is too slow.

```
# Example dataframe
df <- data.frame(category = c("cat 1a",
                        "cat 1a",
                        "cat 1a",
                        "cat 1a, cat 2a",
                        "cat 3a, cat 1a, cat 2b",
                        "cat 1a, cat 2c"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# Create a list with strings split based on the comma
string_list <- strsplit(df$category, split = ",", fixed = TRUE)

# Pre defined categories
category1 <- c("cat 1a", "cat 1b", "cat 1c")
category2 <- c("cat 2a", "cat 2b", "cat 2c")
category3 <- c("cat 3a", "cat 3b", "cat 3c")

# Create new columns based on your categories
df$Category_1 <- sapply(1:length(string_list) , function (x) any(grepl(paste(category1, collapse = "|"), unlist(string_list[x]))) / 
                          length(unlist(string_list[x])))
df$Category_2 <- sapply(1:length(string_list) , function (x) any(grepl(paste(category2, collapse = "|"), unlist(string_list[x]))) / 
                          length(unlist(string_list[x])))
df$Category_3 <- sapply(1:length(string_list) , function (x) any(grepl(paste(category3, collapse = "|"), unlist(string_list[x]))) / 
                          length(unlist(string_list[x])))

df
                category Category_1 Category_2 Category_3
1                 cat 1a  1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
2                 cat 1a  1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
3                 cat 1a  1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
4         cat 1a, cat 2a  0.5000000  0.5000000  0.0000000
5 cat 3a, cat 1a, cat 2b  0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333
6         cat 1a, cat 2c  0.5000000  0.5000000  0.0000000
```

EDIT: using the data that @Gilean0709 kindly provided (and stringi, to make it faster), here is an udpdate:

```
# Example dataframe
df <- data.frame(category = c("Candidate Biography", "Candidate Biography", "Candidate Biography", 
                             "Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance", 
                             "Justice, Candidate Biography, Economy", "Candidate Biography, Jobs", 
                             "Economy, Education, Candidate Biography", 
                             "Economy, Civil Rights, Candidate Biography"), stringsAsFactors = F)


# Create a list with strings split based on the comma
string_list <- strsplit(df$category, split = ",", fixed = TRUE)

library(stringi)

# Pre defined categories
CandBio <- paste(c("Candidate Biography"), collapse = "|")
Economy <- paste(c("Campaign Finance", "Economy", "Jobs"), collapse = "|")
CivilRights <- paste(c("Justice", "Civil Rights"), collapse = "|")
Family <- paste(c("Education"), collapse = "|")

# Create new columns based on your categories
df$CandBio <- sapply(1:length(string_list), function (x) any(stri_detect_regex(unlist(string_list[x]), CandBio)) / 
                          length(unlist(string_list[x])))
df$Economy <- sapply(1:length(string_list), function (x) any(stri_detect_regex(unlist(string_list[x]), Economy)) / 
                          length(unlist(string_list[x])))
df$CivilRights <- sapply(1:length(string_list), function (x) any(stri_detect_regex(unlist(string_list[x]), CivilRights)) / 
                          length(unlist(string_list[x])))
df$Family <- sapply(1:length(string_list), function (x) any(stri_detect_regex(unlist(string_list[x]), Family)) / 
                          length(unlist(string_list[x])))

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)
                                    category CandBio Economy CivilRights Family
1                        Candidate Biography    1.00    0.00        0.00   0.00
2                        Candidate Biography    1.00    0.00        0.00   0.00
3                        Candidate Biography    1.00    0.00        0.00   0.00
4      Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance    0.50    0.50        0.00   0.00
5      Justice, Candidate Biography, Economy    0.33    0.33        0.33   0.00
6                  Candidate Biography, Jobs    0.50    0.50        0.00   0.00
7    Economy, Education, Candidate Biography    0.33    0.33        0.00   0.33
8 Economy, Civil Rights, Candidate Biography    0.33    0.33        0.33   0.00
```

Comment: Thanks! However the number of words is not necessarily related to the numbers assigned to the main categories.  I add an edit to my main questions to make it more clear...

Comment: I do not see how your edit is any different than both answers. Both answers use the # of categories and not the number of words. Could you clarify further?

Comment: Hi Andrews, maybe I then misunderstood... Let me try and I will come back to you... Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, actually, scratch that. Looks like the other solution is based off the number of matches for each row (so each row will always total 100%). Correct me if I am wrong, @Gilean0709. I know the solution I proposed is based off the number of categories in the `category` column of the example dataframe. E.g., `Candidate Biography` is 1, `Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance` is 2. Hope this helps :)

Comment: So lets assume we add to CandBio <- paste(c("Candidate Biography"), collapse = "|") the following CandBio <- paste(c("Candidate Biography", "Civil Rights, Crime, Criminal Justice, Candidate Biography"), collapse = "|"). As a result it would add to CandBio 0.25 (1/ 4 words). Instead I would prefer that I have another list in which I store for each combination the corresponding value and it adds this value then to each aggregated category (i.e. CandBio, etc.)

Comment: But maybe you pointed me on something, so I need to assign the individual words to categories through a list and then let them add (resp. sum up) for each category the values resulting from 1/number of words

Comment: I'll be honest, you lost me. As far as your example, my code would match `Candidate Biography` as 1 for both vectors (overarching groups) you included. Because it is in both. If `Candidate Biography, Campaign Finance` matched with both your `Economy` and `CandBio` group, each would be .5. If only one matched, it would still be .5.